Generate an ID that represents matches of other fields
I have a table in a Snowflake SQL database table:
CREATE TABLE accounts (
  ACCOUNT_ID VARCHAR,
  FIRST_NAME VARCHAR,
  LAST_NAME VARCHAR,
  DATE_OF_BIRTH VARCHAR
  EMAIL VARCHAR,
  PHONE_NUMBER VARCHAR
);

INSERT INTO accounts VALUES
( 'A847290', 'BENJIMAN', 'SISKO', '2332-01-01', 'b.sisko@federation.org', '999999999' ),
( 'B234839', 'BENJIMAN', 'SISKO', NULL, 'b.sisko@federation.org', '999999999' ),
( 'C123594', 'BENJIMAN', 'SISKO', NULL, NULL, NULL ),
( 'A239865', 'BENJIMAN', 'SISKO', '2332-01-01', 'b.sisko@federation.org', NULL ),
( 'Z389202', 'BENJIMAN', 'SISKO', '2332-01-01', NULL, '999999999' );

I would like to use SQL to create an identifier for records which have more than 4 matches for each of the fields. For example, my expected output would be:
ACCOUNT_ID | ID
-----------|--------------
A847290    | I12304 
B234839    | I12304
A239865    | I12304
Z389202    | I12304

The end goal is to be able to build a table that would group accounts to an identifier that would represent an individual of multiple accounts. I also expect there is a many to many relationship between account and individuals.
Thanks!
I have tried to:

Create a self-cartesian join
Filter records where the match number is > 3
Create a hash of the values for a identifier

SELECT    a1.ACCOUNT_ID
        , a2.FIRST_NAME
        , a2.LAST_NAME
        , a2.DATE_OF_BIRTH
        , a2.EMAIL
        , a2.PHONE_NUMBER
        , MD5(a2.FIRST_NAME, a2.LAST_NAME, a2.DATE_OF_BIRTH, a2.EMAIL, a2.PHONE_NUMBER) AS ID
FROM    accounts a1
JOIN    accounts a2
ON      (IFF(a1.FIRST_NAME = a2.FIRST_NAME, 1, 0) 
        + IFF(a1.LAST_NAME = a2.LAST_NAME, 1, 0)
        + IFF(a1.DATE_OF_BIRTH = a2.DATE_OF_BIRTH, 1, 0)
        + IFF(a1.EMAIL = a2.EMAIL, 1, 0)
        + IFF(a1.PHONE_NUMBER = a2.PHONE_NUMBER, 1, 0)) > 3

The problem is that in the example above each record will get a different ID as the match fields are not consistent even though there is a match > 3.

What do you want as result, if  is match4(A,B) and match4(B,C) and not match4(A,C) ?

I am wondering about the following approach... Now you might not want to do the primary_no_match portion and you might only want to output ID2 and not ID1 in the final output, but I feel like something along these lines could work for you.  Let me know.  Try playing around with it and running only certain parts of the CTE.
WITH duplicates AS
  (SELECT ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY_SORT(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(a1.ACCOUNT_ID || a2.ACCOUNT_ID, '.{1}')), '') as combined_id,
          a1.ACCOUNT_ID AS id1,
          a2.ACCOUNT_ID AS id2,
          (IFF(a1.FIRST_NAME is null, 1, 0) 
          + IFF(a1.LAST_NAME is null, 1, 0) 
          + IFF(a1.DATE_OF_BIRTH is null, 1, 0) 
          + IFF(a1.EMAIL is null, 1, 0) 
          + IFF(a1.PHONE_NUMBER is null, 1, 0)) as null_count,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY combined_id ORDER BY null_count, id1) AS row_num,
          MD5(IFNULL(a1.FIRST_NAME, '') 
          || IFNULL(a1.LAST_NAME, '') 
          || IFNULL(a1.DATE_OF_BIRTH, '') 
          || IFNULL(a1.EMAIL, '') 
          || IFNULL(a1.PHONE_NUMBER, '')) AS ID
   FROM accounts AS a1
   INNER JOIN accounts AS a2 ON (a1.ACCOUNT_ID <> a2.ACCOUNT_ID
                                 AND (IFF(a1.FIRST_NAME = a2.FIRST_NAME, 1, 0) 
                                 + IFF(a1.LAST_NAME = a2.LAST_NAME, 1, 0) 
                                 + IFF(a1.DATE_OF_BIRTH = a2.DATE_OF_BIRTH, 1, 0) 
                                 + IFF(a1.EMAIL = a2.EMAIL, 1, 0) 
                                 + IFF(a1.PHONE_NUMBER = a2.PHONE_NUMBER, 1, 0)) > 3)
   ORDER by COMBINED_ID, null_count, a1.ACCOUNT_ID, a2.ACCOUNT_ID),
secondaries as
  (select ID1, ID2, ID
   from duplicates
   where row_num = 1
   order by ID1, ID2),
primary as
  (select ID1, ID1 as ID2, ID
   from secondaries
   group by all
   order by ID1), 
primary_no_match as
  (select ACCOUNT_ID as ID1,
          ACCOUNT_ID as ID2,
          MD5(IFNULL(FIRST_NAME, '') 
          || IFNULL(LAST_NAME, '') 
          || IFNULL(DATE_OF_BIRTH, '') 
          || IFNULL(EMAIL, '') 
          || IFNULL(PHONE_NUMBER, '')) AS ID
   from accounts
   where ACCOUNT_ID not in
       (SELECT ID1 as IDX FROM primary UNION ALL SELECT ID2 as IDX from secondaries))
select ID1, ID2, ID from primary
UNION ALL
select ID1, ID2, ID from secondaries
UNION ALL
select ID1, ID2, ID from primary_no_match
order by ID1, ID2

;

The results of the query look like:



ID1
ID2
ID




A847290
A239865
efc046bda7a6dae3ab76ea55d5bb74fb


A847290
A847290
efc046bda7a6dae3ab76ea55d5bb74fb


A847290
B234839
efc046bda7a6dae3ab76ea55d5bb74fb


A847290
Z389202
efc046bda7a6dae3ab76ea55d5bb74fb


C123594
C123594
3229d994a531415d6f622d506287d232



